# WHS sub directories permissions, can they be managed?

Tags: permissions, windows-home-server

I have a Windows Home Server with multiple PCs and Macs connected.  I also have about a dozen or so users and the list is growing.  I desire the ability to control user access to a finer detail then what the WHS console seems to provide.

For example, I have the Pictures share and under it hundreds of sub directories. I would like user 'Grandparents' to only be able to access the directory with my kids pictures.

I have searched through all the add-ins, googled till my eyes started to bleed and only came up with [cacls](http://www.ss64.com/nt/cacls.html).

Is it even possible to achieve this level of permissions with WHS?  If so, is cacls my answer?

Any other info would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you understand SHARE and NTFS permissions then yes it is possible. Home server basically creates local accounts and then a whole bunch of groups for each user and folder with different rights.

SO you could create the user account for your grandparents as you would normally in Home server. 
Log onto the Home server and figure out what home server named the group ( they are commented pretty well) Then assign that group an entry share at the folder level that works and modify the ntfs permissions allowing them to inherit down. Removing the group from any folders that you don't want them to see.

if you don't understand any of this them don't even try, its pretty easy to really dig yourself into a hole

Comment: Agreed, under the covers WHS is just Windows Server 2003, so you could still modify directory permissions in the same manner if you knew what to look for.

Comment: I will try this out tonight.  I am not too nervous about messing things up.  I will create an image of the server before I start to make sure.